# Easy Delegate ve Event issue

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

it was work before but now not working why i dont know  what is the issue?

in example have 2 forms form1 have 1 button form2 have 1 textbox when start the program and click the button  form1 should close, form2 open and delegate variable should write in textbox but not work. Error is "System.NullReferenceException occurred"

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void kapatici(string al);
    public static event kapatici kapat;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        kapat("deneme");
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.kapat += Form1_kapat;
    }

    private void Form1_kapat(string al)
    {
        textBox1.Text = al;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've tried different types like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.ShowDialog();
    kapat("deneme");
}
```

but still not working.
thank you for your answers.

Comment: We do not add "solved" to a title on Stack Overflow. If you have in fact solved the problem, post an _answer_ to the question and click the "accept" button on that answer.

Comment: We also do not answer questions that have already been asked and answered before. If after following the extensive advice in the marked duplicate, you still cannot solve the problem, post a new question explaining what you've done already to diagnose the problem, and express your question in a manner that goes beyond simply stating that your code throws `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Hi Peter, actualy i saw your  linked subject before wrote that question. But i coudnt find right solition for me. Sorry if my entry is duplicate. 2nd point is didnt click the accept button because i didnt try answer i dont want to manipulate who search answers. 3rd point is i found a solition different way before answer to my question. The problem is algorithmic The delegate stack on opening new form and i changed way delegate position between forms and it works. I know this is not best solition but its work and i couldnt write here because this is not professionel solition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the code - but I think / hope it's just a minimal example. So here is a solution:

Events are null until they are suscribed. You have to check the event before you are going to invoke it:

```
if (kapat =! null)
{
  kapat.Invoke("deneme");
}
```

A compact way to do this is by using the null-operator:

```
kapat?.Invoke("deneme");
```

Second mistake is to show your second form as dialog, because you are blocking your method until the dialog is closed. If your click-method looks like this, it will work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.Show();
    kapat?.Invoke("deneme");
}
```

If you only want to show a text on your second form, you should not use a event. The simplest way is to pass the string throught the constructor of the second form like:

```
public Form2(string al)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = al;
}
```

Now you can open the form with:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2("deneme");
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try.